# Store data in backend using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, database, swift, kinvey

I am developing an application using Kinvey as backend. And I have an array of objects `Questions` that I need to store in the database which consists of `Qnumber` , `Qanswer1` and `Qanswer2` properties. My problem is when I try to save this array of questions in the database it always saves the last object in the array n times.

Suppose I have these data stored in the array:

```
Questions[0].Qnumber = 1
Questions[0].Qanswer1 = "a1"
Questions[0].Qanswer2 = "b1"

Questions[1].Qnumber = 2
Questions[1].Qanswer1 = "a2"
Questions[1].Qanswer2 = "b2"

Questions[2].Qnumber = 3
Questions[2].Qanswer1 = "a3"
Questions[2].Qanswer2 = "b3"
```

When I save these objects in the backend using a loop and check the database I get:

Qnumber : 3 , 3 , 3
Qanswer1 : a3, a3 , a3
Qanswer2: b3, b3, b3

I spent 2 days trying to solve this but I couldn't
Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let i = Int(numberOfQuestions)
    var newQ : Questions = Questions()
    for var index = 0; index < i; ++index {
        newQ.Qnumber = String(index + 1)
        newQ.Qanswer1 = cellAnswer1[index]
        newQ.Qanswer2 = cellAnswer2[index]
        saveObject(newQ)
    }
}

func saveObject (newQuestion: Questions){
    let store = KCSAppdataStore.storeWithOptions([
        KCSStoreKeyCollectionName : "Questions",
        KCSStoreKeyCollectionTemplateClass : Questions.self
        ])


    store.saveObject(
        newQuestion,
        withCompletionBlock: { (objectsOrNil: [AnyObject]!, errorOrNil: NSError!) -> Void in
            if errorOrNil != nil {
                NSLog("an error happened: %@", errorOrNil)
            } else {
                //save was successful
                NSLog("A new question is saved sucessfully")
            }
        },
        withProgressBlock: nil
    )
}
```

Comment: Assuming your Questions object is a collection type, have you tried moving your call to saveObjext(newQ) to outside of your loop? My bet is that it is saving three times because your count property is 3 and this your loops runs three times on each question.

Comment: Or move the newQ property inside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to put the initial of newQ into the for loop

```
for var index = 0; index < i; ++index {
    var newQ : Questions = Questions()
    newQ.Qnumber = String(index + 1)
    newQ.Qanswer1 = cellAnswer1[index]
    newQ.Qanswer2 = cellAnswer2[index]
    saveObject(newQ)
}
```